Python - no output
`While using the following code / example in Spyder 5.5.4 / conda 3.11.7 I wont get any output
beginning from -> *print("No Output") see bold.
by using console e.g. print("no Output") I get the output.
Any suggestions?
%matplotlib qt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pymarket as pm
import pprint
r = np.random.RandomState(1234)
mar = pm.Market()
mar.accept_bid(1, 6.7, 0, True, 0)
mar.accept_bid(1, 6.6, 1, True, 0)
mar.accept_bid(1, 6.5, 2, True, 0)
mar.accept_bid(1, 6.4, 3, True, 0)
mar.accept_bid(1, 6.3, 4, True, 0)
mar.accept_bid(1, 6, 5, True, 0)

mar.accept_bid(1, 1, 6, False, 0)
mar.accept_bid(1, 2, 7, False, 0)
mar.accept_bid(2, 3, 8, False, 0)
mar.accept_bid(2, 4, 9, False, 0)
mar.accept_bid(1, 6.1, 10, False, 0)

bids = mar.bm.get_df()
transactions, extras = mar.run('p2p', r=r)
stats = mar.statistics()
***print("No Output")***

bids # bids dataframe
transactions.get_df() # transactions dataframe

extras # additional information characteristic of P2P trading,

mar.plot()
ax = mar.plot_method('p2p')


print('Percentage of the maximum possible traded quantity')
stats['percentage_traded']`

tried to restart kerel,
tried output in console -> which is working

I don't really know much stuff about the library you are using, but you can try, as an alternative, to "manually" printing data to the stdout like so:
import sys
_ = sys.stdout.write('Percentage of the maximum possible traded quantity\n')

Notice the differences between print() and sys.stdout.write(): using the second one implies you to add manually a newline character and, since the function returns stuff, most of the time you'll need to manage the output, here it's setting the output to _ since this variable name is often used as a "trash".
If this code works, then this is a problem with the print() function: maybe a module changed it.
Else, there's a problem with something other (I don't think it can be the terminal, and I have no other idea of what it could be).

Thank you for the answer. Tried it, unfortunately the same issue.
I tried the libraries today for the first time, so I am not sure whether they work properly.
One of the libraries seem to call the "CBC MILP Solver" and somehow it seems that after the solver was called no further output is possible. I do get the results, but I cant print the results or do anything else, as it seems that after the solver has been called the output is restricted.

@dertisalisda12 seems like you use Jupyter. Have you tried without it ? Like in a regular Python script ?
